# Is it possible to create a HDFS folder in memory?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Hadoop now supports mount a ramdisk (tmpfs), is it possible to create a hdfs folder pure in tmpfs, like all files in "/usr/memory" locate in ramdisk

Comment: Hadoop has always supported arbitrary file locations. What attempts have you made to try to it?

Comment: I found the solution w/ LAZY_PERSIST, thanks.

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question below in detail rather than leave it in the comments